# ebay api - send xml request via php

Tags: php, xml, curl, ebay-api

Can anyone see what I'm missing? I keep getting no response, The xml file is correct, so are the headers and url but I'm not getting anything in response.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $URL = $_REQUEST['URL'];
    $site = $_REQUEST['site'];
    $file = fopen($URL, 'r');
    $xmlRequest = fread($file, filesize($URL));
    echo "<textarea>" . $xmlRequest . "</textarea>"; //this is me making sure the file
                                                     //actually contains the xml doc

    $endpoint = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";
    $session  = curl_init($endpoint);                       // create a curl session

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);              // POST request type
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest); // set the body of the POST
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    // return values as a string - not to std out
    $headers = array(
      'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetCategories',
      'X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID: ' . $site,
      'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: *****',
      'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: *****',
      'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: *****',
      'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 761',
      'X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING: XML',    // for a POST request, the response by default is in the same format as the request
      'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8'
    );
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    //set headers using the above array of headers

    $responseXML = curl_exec($session);                     // send the request
    curl_close($session);

    if ($responseXML = '' OR $responseXML = ' ') {
      echo "Failed!";
    }
    echo $responseXML;
    return $responseXML;  // returns a string

?>
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. Curl has the [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/curl_error) function that will tell you what went wrong with a request.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out in the end, changed the code almost completely but I got it to work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$xml_response =  simplexml_load_string($responseXML);
```

Inside of this xml_response you must find Ack

```
$xml_response->Ack
```

the values can be : Warning, Failure or Success and gives you the type of error (if there was an error in the request)